# Python: Reinforcement learning Tic-Tac-Toe AI working?

Tags: python

So I'm scratching my head at this, and I don't know what's wrong. The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/x207nUgw). The idea is that the AI plays games against itself, and is rewarded for winning or drawing, and punished for losing. Given a board, the AI will choose a move with certain weights. If the game ends up being a win or draw, those moves that it selected will have their weights increased. If the game ends up being a loss, those moves that it selected will have their weights decreased.

Instead what I observe is that 1) The 'X' player (Player 1) will almost always go for either the top left or bottom right square, rather than in the middle as expected, and 2) The 'X' player will become more and more favoured to win as the number of games increases.

I have no idea what is causing this behaviour, and I would appreciate any help.

Apparently stackoverflow requires you to also put code in to use pastebin, so here is the reward bit, although it probably makes more sense in the full context linked above.

```
foo = ai_player
for i in range(0,len(moves_made)):
    # Find the index of the move made
    weight_index = foo.children.index(moves_made[i])
    
    # If X won
    if checkWin(current_player.placements) == 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            foo.weights[weight_index] += 10
        else:
            foo.weights[weight_index] -= 10
            if foo.weights[weight_index] <= 0: foo.weights[weight_index] = 0
            
    # If O won
    if checkWin(current_player.placements) == -1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            foo.weights[weight_index] -= 10
            if foo.weights[weight_index] <= 0: foo.weights[weight_index] = 0
        else:
            foo.weights[weight_index] += 10
    
    # If it was a draw
    if checkWin(current_player.placements) == 0:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            foo.weights[weight_index] += 5
        else:
            foo.weights[weight_index] += 5

    foo = foo.children[weight_index]
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I had to downvote this question - the code as provided applies simple heuristics without fully grasping what RL is. Please be sure to look at basic explanations and implementations of RL, such as the one found here, which is literally the first result I got for Googling "Reinforcement Learning Python":
https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-reinforcement-learning-with-python/

Also, see @AverageHomosapien's great answer for more details (you should accept it imho).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of issues with your original code for trying to get agents to learn.

1. You use absolute weights instead of some calculated heuristic for the weights. When adding weights, you want to use an update mechanism (e.g. Q-Learning).
   [image: Q-Learning Algorithm] [Wikipedia Q-Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning)

This bounds the board weights between the range of possible rewards and allows new, promising options to rise, given positive rewards (having a score +100 or +200 will be very hard to beat).

2. You assign weightings to the board indexes and not board positions. This will teach agents that certain squares of the board are 'the best' and other squares aren't regardless of the utility. (i.e. if there are X's on square 0 and square 1, and O thinks their 'absolute' best move is bottom right, however X can win next turn).
3. Moves seem to be random in this environment (as far as I can see). The agents need some way of 'exploring' to find which moves work and which moves don't, and then 'exploiting' the best moves found so far.
4. You only store the 'state' values and not the value of taking actions in a given state. With this, agents can calculate the value of the state they're in, but they need a way of calculating the value of actions they can take, to inform them of the best actions to take.

[image: RL Framework]

In the Reinforcement Learning framework, the agent takes in the state and needs to evaluate the best possible action to take, given the state.

I've re-written your code, using a Q-learning table to get the agents moving appropriately (moving the agents into a class). Also using NumPy for argmax etc functions.

Q-Learning function is:

```
self.Q_table[(state, action)] = q_val + 0.1 * \
(reward + self.return_value[(state, action)] / self.return_number[(state, action)])
```

Code is in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fk6Dx3nx).

- With Epsilon of 0.08 and 1,000,000 episodes, the win rate for X was ~16%, Y was ~7% and about ~77% draws.
- With Epsilon of 0.04 and 1,000,000 episodes, the win rate for X was ~9%, Y was ~3% and about ~88% draws.
- With Epsilon of 0.04 and 2,000,000 episodes - almost identical results to 1m episodes.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just like this but possibly you reward them for playing draws and it keeps happening?

Also, you should evaluate checkWin() once at the start and you could make a simple function like update(weight) and pass 10, -10 or 5 depending on your case

Is your algorithm:
0. init all weights to 100 for every board state

1. reset board
2. get board state
3. make a random (weighted) move depending on weights/board state
4. check if the game ends, if so update weights and go back to 1, else go to 2
   ?

Comment: My algorithm works as you describes, yes.

Comment: and you pick a random number between 0 and sum of all weights for this board configuration, and from that random number you pick the move associated?

Comment: Yes, that is what the random.choices function does.

Comment: also you can do "For move_made in moves_made" in python.

You could try doing just 1 iteration and see how the weights are affected.

Comment: I need to know the index though, because the weights are modified depending on whether it was X or O making it.